# How to check if the wget command request was served by a particular server when load balancer is in place?

Tags: python, linux, wget

I want to verify Stickiness policy of load balancer. Hence want to verify that when I make two or three subsequent HTTP requests (wget), then the request is satisfied by the same server every time?

Comment: I think this is more about the *Stickiness policy of load balancer* and less about python or wget etc, and so I think this should be better suited for serverfault.

Comment: I am guessing there would be some parameters that I can send/receive in wget command, or there is some linux trick to get the hostname or something from http request?

Answer (score 0):

Send a unique header on the backend server, E.G., "X-Node-ID: 1" for server #1.

Comment: Does that mean I have to change setting on server?

Comment: Yes. This question is actually better-suited for ServerFault rather than StackOverflow, unless your server is a pure Python app with no frontend.